# Electrostatics: Finite Elements

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I'm messing around with FEM in mathematica and am having trouble solving a very simple problem of the electric field around a unifromly charged sphere.

Here is my workflow.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]

(* Define Boundary *)
domain = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}]];
circle = ToBoundaryMesh[Disk[]];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[domain, circle]

(* Define Elements *)
air = {0, 2};
sphere = {0, 0};
markerSpecification = {{air, 1}, {dielectric, 2}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> markerSpecification, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1, "NodeReordering" -> True];
mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm /@{White, LightRed}]]
```

[image]

```
(* Solve Laplaces equation with charge density = 1 inside the unit disk *)
usol = NDSolveValue[{-Laplacian[v[x, y], {x, y}] == 
    Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}}, 0]
     (* Set potential to 1 on the boundary of the disk *)
   , DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 1]}
  , v, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
ContourPlot[usol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

[image]

Thats really not the result I expected since the solution should be
`Piecewise[{{r^2/4, r < 1}}, Log[r]/2 + 1/4]`

I also get even worse results if I make the potential = 0 on the boundary.

Comment: You solve the 2D problem for the disk, but you are trying to compare it with the solution for the sphere. `Piecewise[{{r, r <= 1}}, 1/r^2]` it a solution for a charged sphere for radial component of the electric field, not for potential.

Comment: This [link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893965911002564) might be interesting for you.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thats a good point it's the cross section of a cylinder so should be log(r) for the potential and 1/r for the field

Comment: @AlexTrounev Asymptotically, the potential should be $1/r$ as follows from the series expansion of the elliptic functions, not $\log(r)$

Comment: As soon as the total charge is 0, the sum of the contributions is 1/r in the expansion, but a charge **alone** contributes as Log[r] (in 2 D).

Comment: see : `AsymptoticEqual[1/r, Log[r] - Log[r + 1] , r -> Infinity]` gives True

Comment: Because the potential is fully specified at the boundary of the disk (`DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x^2 + y^2 == 1`), the potential inside the disk is totally independent of what is outside the disk, and vice versa. So the problem must be seen as two independent problems (physically speaking the disk boundary is a Faraday cage).

Comment: @andre314 but I have to specify the potential somehwere? Do you suggest I always do as the answer below suggests and just specify it at the boundary of the computational domain?

Comment: It depends on your real problem. The most probable is that effectively you don't have to specify the potential at the boundary of the disk. I say "probable" because otherwise, it means that this boundary is a conductor (though  the inside stays insulated). By the way, it would be easier to have a idea of the real physical problem. I suspect that "uniformly charged" is wrong hypothesis.

Comment: Another possibility is that "by uniformly charged", you mean that the charge is uniform at the boundary of the disk (or sphere). In that case the charge inside the disk is 0. It is the classical case of a conducting disk (or sphere), and in that case we don't care of what's inside.

Answer (score 5):

We solve the problem for the disk and compare the numerical solution and the analytical

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg = Rectangle[{-3., -3.}, {3., 3.}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, 
    area > 0.0001 (0.1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
mesh["Wireframe"]

eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= 1}}, 0];
bc = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Log[x^2 + y^2]/4 + 1/4, True];
U = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
```

Here, on the left, the two solutions almost coincide; on the right, the difference of solutions

```
{Plot[{U[x, 0], 
   Piecewise[{{x^2/4, -1 <= x <= 1}, {Log[x^2]/4 + 1/4, 
      True}}]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> {"FEM", "Analytical"}], 
 Plot[{U[x, 0] - 
    Piecewise[{{x^2/4, -1 <= x <= 1}, {Log[x^2]/4 + 1/4, 
       True}}]}, {x, -3, 3}]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Potential and electric field

```
f = Evaluate[-Grad[U[x, y], {x, y}]];

ContourPlot[U[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh, Contours -> 20, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]

StreamDensityPlot[f, {x, y} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Alex, please provide some clarity for me with this answer, can you use these same techniques to do magnetic fields? Your answers seem so simple when I see them, and it would be great to see an example with a uniformly magnetized sphere ;)

Comment: @CATrevillian Another issue is discussed here. But if you open the topic and show the code, then perhaps we can solve your problem. For the magnetic field there are other algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, any insight why my approach failed? What if we had a more complex object then a sphere and wanted to specify the charge density based on a mesh? For example I would like to see worflow for solving the efeild around this ```Import["https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/552/\
501/large_2x/vector-heart-romantic-love-graphic.jpg"] // ColorNegate //
    ImageMesh // 
  RegionResize[#, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}] & // ToBoundaryMesh``` assuming it is uniformely charged.

Comment: This link is unavailable.

Comment: A line break character was inserted use "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/552/501/large_2x/vector-heart-romantic-love-graphic.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to get much better accuracy for u in much less time.

Because this has a discontinuity it is better to make a mesh that respects that.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
reg = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{-3., -3.}, {3., 3.}], Disk[]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
  "RegionMarker" -> {{{0, 0}, 1}, {{2, 0}, 2}}]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

This has about 640 elements.

I also added markers which makes the equation set up a bit easier I find:

```
eq = Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == If[ElementMarker == 1, 1, 0];
bc = DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == Log[x^2 + y^2]/4 + 1/4, True];
sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, bc}, u, {x, y} \[Element] mesh];
```

This computes the error to the analytical solution.

```
Plot[{
  sol[x, 0] - 
   Piecewise[{{x^2/4, -1 <= x <= 1}, {Log[x^2]/4 + 1/4, True}}], 
  U[x, 0] - 
   Piecewise[{{x^2/4, -1 <= x <= 1}, {Log[x^2]/4 + 1/4, 
      True}}]}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The orange line is the result from Alex the blue line is this computation.